# How to filter using OR and AND

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to create code to filter my catagory and tag, I'm using select box to filter, my code like this:

```
if ($filter2) {
    $addedCondition = " AND (nama_kat LIKE '%$filter2%' OR nama_tag LIKE '%$filter2%') ";
}
  $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM konten
    WHERE (nama_kat LIKE '%$filter1%'
    OR nama_tag LIKE '%$filter2%') ".$addedCondition."
    ORDER BY 'date' DESC");
```

work if I'm only filter one word, but once I filter with two words it's not working, my web displaying all articles.

you can try filter here http://stanime.pe.hu/

Comment: Please `echo $query` so we can discuss the SQL generated.  Do a working 1-word case and a not-working 2-word case.

Comment: Did you intend to have `$filter2` in the first check?

Answer (score 0):

You have to explode your string into words and use OR.

```
$addedCondition = '';
$filter2 = explode(' ',$filter2);
foreach($filter2 as $word)
{
    $addedCondition .= " OR (nama_kat LIKE '%$word%' OR nama_tag LIKE '%$word%') ";
}
```